# What does 'echo' do within a perl variable declaration?

Tags: perl

I am working on transcribing an outdated file from perl to python and got caught up with some perl syntax.

```
my $jobID = `echo \$JOBID`;
chomp($jobID);
unless ($jobID) {
  print "Please specify a job\n";
  exit;
}
```

Thus far, I have been able to transcribe all of the command-line parsing extremely easily but am very fairly stuck here with what exactly this code is doing (specifically the **echo** within the declaration on line 1).

Within the perl script cmd-line parsing options - that enables one to set the jobID - it states that "default = $JOBID". So my assumption is that the first line in this code simply sets this default jobID until one is specified.

If this is the case why would you need to use echo within the variable default declaration? Is this good practice in perl or am I missing a larger picture?

I have tried searching low and high for this but can't seem to google ninja my way to anything useful.

Any help on the 'echo' would be greatly appreciated (or any good reads on this as well)!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is one way to get a value from a shell variable.  The backticks (`` ` ``) run the shell command and give you the output.  So the `echo` is running inside of a shell and in this case it just returns the one shell variable.  A cleaner way to get this in Perl is to use `%ENV` like so:

```
 my $jobID = $ENV{'JOBID'};
```

This also removes the need for `chomp`, avoids creating an extra process, and is much more efficient.

Comment: Awesome! Very clear and concise, very much appreciated!

Comment: Reading an environment variable directly is also much faster.

Answer (score 3):

It is evaluating an environment variable named `$JOBID` and storing the result in `$jobID`, which (as duskwuff points out) is better accomplished using `$ENV{JOBID}`.

The backticks around the `echo \$JOBID` tell Perl to invoke the specified command in a subshell and return the output of the invoked command.

Comment: Which is better accomplished using `$ENV{JOBID}`. No need for a subshell.